# Loud screech when starting my 2008 Matrix

Tags: toyota, noise, matrix

Only when I start my 2008 Matrix 100.000 miles, I hear a loud screeching noise. I've checked the belts, they all look good. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks Roger

Comment: That's an absolutely classic description of belt noise, could you have somebody start the car for you while you listen with the hood open? Also are there times when it doesn't happen? Does it happen when the engine catches or a few seconds later?

Comment: Also look to see if there is something else that start with the engine. A fan perhaps? But it is almost certainly something being suddenly accelerated as the engine starts. With the age of your vehicle the belts might be tight enough, but hardening and loosing "traction" so that they slip as the engine comes up to speed.

Comment: Can you record it and post it here? Screech when starting is either belt with too much slack or starter on it's way out.

Comment: Animals often use the engine compartments of vehicles as homes because they offer shelter and warmth. When you start the vehicle, this startles the animal and causes it to screech.